# Key Bruteforcing

Tags: python, brute-force

I need to find a password key.  The length of the key is **10** characters and the order of the letters in the key is **3,7,2,1,4,5,6,10,8,9**.  I also know the md5 of the key.

So I wrote

```
mystring = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for letter3 in mystring:
    for letter7 in mystring[mystring.index(letter3):]:
        for letter2 in mystring[:mystring.index(letter7)]:
            for letter1 in mystring[:mystring.index(letter2)]:
                for letter4 in mystring[mystring.index(letter1):]:
                    for letter5 in mystring[mystring.index(letter4):]:
                        for letter6 in mystring[mystring.index(letter4):]:
                            for letter10 in mystring[mystring.index(leter6):]:  
                                for letter8 in mystring[:mystring.index(letter10)]:
                                    for letter9 in mystring[mystring.index(letter8):]:
                                        strr = "".join([letter1,letter2,letter3,letter4,letter5,letter6,letter7,letter8,letter9,letter10])
                                        if hashlib.md5(strr).hexdigest() == md5:
                                            print "key = " ,strr
                                            break
```

The order of characters:

### The key:

```
|letter1|letter2|letter3|letter4|letter5|letter6|letter7|letter8|letter9|letter10|
```

### The key sorted alphabetically:

```
|letter3|letter7|letter2|letter1|letter4|letter5|letter6|letter10|letter8|letter9|
```

The problem is the time (It take ~ 6 hours for one iteration in the outside loop ). Any suggestions to optimize the range of **for** loops?

Comment: what does `the order of the letters in the key is 3,7,2,1,4,5,6,10,8,9.` mean?

Comment: The numbers are the sorting order of the characters.  If you sort the key lexicographically, then the 1st letter moves to the 3rd position.  The 2nd letter moves to the 7th position, &ct.

Comment: It means that the key in the form of `"letter1,letter2,letter3,..."` and when I sort it get `"letter3,letter7,letter2,..",`

Comment: @QuestionC Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Should I change it so the code is more readable?

Comment: Nah.  Your code is correct.  It's just a little confused about how to sort the letters.

Comment: @QuestionC I hope it's more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try any of the online hash crackers?

Comment: @Chaker.benhamed do you need to do it only once (find a key by its md5 hash)?

Comment: @Alik Yes i already have the md5. So I compare the md5 of every possible key to the one that I have.

Comment: @Chaker.benhamed can you post it?

Comment: @alik Of course `a50e38475041f76219748ee22c4377d4`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The solution is at the bottom**

---

You're very close.  What you want is this...

```
mystring = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for letter1 in mystring:
    for letter2 in mystring[mystring.index(letter1):]:
        for letter3 in mystring[mystring.index(letter2):]:
            for letter4 in mystring[mystring.index(letter3):]:
                for letter5 in mystring[mystring.index(letter4):]:
                    for letter6 in mystring[mystring.index(letter5):]:
                        for letter7 in mystring[mystring.index(letter6):]:
                            for letter8 in mystring[mystring.index(leter7):]:  
                                for letter9 in mystring[mystring.index(letter8):]:
                                    for letter10 in mystring[mystring.index(letter9):]:
                                        strr = "".join([letter3,letter7,letter2,letter1,letter4,letter5,letter6,letter10,letter8,letter9])
                                        if hashlib.md5(strr).hexdigest() == md5:
                                            print "key = " ,strr
                                            break
```

That loop seriously cuts down on the number of iterations because you're searching many fewer characters.  Each loop searches fewer characters than its outer loop.  Note how it's much more organized with each loop searching in the same direction.

But it is also **very slow** because `mystring.index()` is a slow operation.  We can make it faster by not using `mystring.index()`...

```
mystring = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for i1 in range(len(mystring)):
    for i2 in range(i1, len(mystring)):
        for i3 in range(i2, len(mystring)):
            for i4 in range(i3, len(mystring)):
                for i5 in range(i4, len(mystring)):
                    for i6 in range(i5, len(mystring)):
                        for i7 in range (i6, len(mystring)):
                            for i8 in range (i7, len(mystring)):
                                for i9 in range (i8, len(mystring)):
                                    for i10 in range (i9, len(mystring)):
                                        strr = "".join([mystring[i3], mystring[i7], mystring[i2], mystring[i1], mystring[i4], mystring[i5], mystring[i6], mystring[i10], mystring[i8], mystring[i9]])
                                        if hashlib.md5(strr).hexdigest() == md5:
                                            print "key = " ,strr
                                            break
```

This is still super slow though, just because it's a huge number of iterations.

The trick here is itertools...

```
mystring = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

import itertools

for L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8, L9, L10 in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(mystring, 10):
    strr = "".join([L3, L7, L2, L1, L4, L5, L6, L10, L8, L9])
    if hashlib.md5(strr).hexdigest() == 'a50e38475041f76219748ee22c4377d4':
        print ('key = {}'.format(strr))
        break
```

`itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` is how you handle these sorts of nested loops where A >= B >= C >= &ct in python and it's quite fast.  This is the fastest possible solution afaik.

Comment: I changed the solution to use combinations_with_replacement instead of combinations.  See the difference here... https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: I also updated the solution to be Python3 since that's what I was testing on.

Comment: I did almost the same as you and found, that the key was `do******`

Comment: Aww, don't post the answer.  Let's just say it started with `d` =)

Comment: You could also use `enumerate` and slicing for your second suggestion, rather than the much hated iteration over a `range`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what is the cause of the difference in time between the solution that I posted and this solution? Exactly what made `combinations_with_replacement()` very fast?

Comment: Well, for starters `combinations_with_replacement()` is implemented in C while anything we write would be done in Python.

Also, the module author probably understands efficient iteration more than you or I since he wrote an entire module devoted to it.  I can't get deeper than that because I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

If you compile it down to machine code, you find that for loop amounts to four parts. First the current iteration integer is loaded from memory, and the letter from the given array is loaded. Then whatever is within your for loop executes, and finally the index is incremented and a conditional jump is performed back to the beginning of the for loop if the condition still holds.

The only way to optimise the process (although I cannot claim about python; I've tried to optimise C's for loops) is to get rid of the increment part and use constants instead. That is, manually layout the iteration of letters. That is, get rid of the for loop and copy and paste thousand of lines of code instead. This is obviously not very ideal and not reusable, and the for loop we set out to optimise is, well, gone.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that for loop is very optimised already, being something very fundamental in assembly. You are trying to brute force it after all.